# Django/AJAX: Sending and receiving a response with POST

Tags: python, json, ajax, django, django-views

I am tinkering with Javascript/JQuery, AJAX, JSON and GeoDjango all for the first time tonight and I'm all mixed up!

So far I have been able to successfully submit a search query from AJAX via a POST request, execute the search in Django, then pass the serialized data back to AJAX. However, I can't figure out how to decode it again with AJAX!

I am receiving this error: `(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined)`

when I add in the following attempt to do something with the data:

```
$.each (json.results, function (i, val) {
                //Loop through each returned item and push onto name
                name.push(val.id);

                //Loop through each returned item and push name onto var zip
                zip.push(val.name);
            });
```

I think this is the relevant Ajax:

```
var name = [];
var zip =  [];

...

//Grab form data
// Submit on submit
$('#event_form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!");  // sanity check
    search_zip();
    //define and set variables
        var searchForm  = $("#event_form").val();
    return false;
});



// AJAX for submitting search query
function search_zip() {
    console.log("event form functional"); // sanity check
    $.ajax({
        url : "/discover/",
        type : "POST", //http method
        data : { event_search : $('#search_box').val() }, // data sent with POST request

    // handle a successful response
    success : function(json) {
        $('#search_box').val(''); // remove the value from the input
        console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
        console.log("success"); // another sanity check

        $.each (json.results, function (i, val) {
            //Loop through each returned item and push onto name
            name.push(val.name);

            //Loop through each returned item and push name onto var zip
            zip.push(val.zip);
        });

        console.log(name);
        console.log(zip);
    },

    // handle a non-successful response
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
            " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
    }});
}
```

and my view just in case:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from AlmondKing.Events.models import Event
from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation

class MapView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index2.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.POST['event_search']:
            self.object = Event.objects.search(request.POST['event_search'])
            return HttpResponse(serialize('geojson',self.object), content_type="application/json")
        else:
            raise SuspiciousOperation("Blank Request Received")
```

Sample Output:

```
b'{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}, "features": [{"properties": {"tags": [], "name": "Party", "zip": "19146"}, "geometry": null, "type": "Feature"}, {"properties": {"tags": [], "name": "Jamboree", "zip": "19146"}, "geometry": null, "type": "Feature"}]}'
```

I am confused at how to help AJAX understand the data. I am using POST so that I can execute a function in my class based TemplateView. However, it seems like the AJAX settings for POST don't work so well for deciphering the serialized response. How can I do all this off of one request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sequence that finally worked for me:

```
$.each (json.features, function (i, val)
    name.push(val.properties.name);
    zip.push(val.properties.zip);
});
```

`name` , `zip` and `tags` are my model columns. The rest is Django's JSON. I should point out that I am using the [GeoJSON serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/) here.

Here is a chart I made to help me visualize the JSON pattern:

```
{"type": 
    "FeatureCollection", 

    "crs": {
        "type": "name",  
        "properties":  {
            "name": "EPSG:4326" 
        }}, 

    "features": [{
            "geometry": null, 
            "properties": {
                "zip": "19146", 
                "name": "Jamboree", 
                "tags": []}, 
                "type": "Feature"
            }, 

            {
            "geometry": null, 
            "properties": {
                "zip": "19146", 
                "name": "Party", 
                "tags": []}, 
                "type": "Feature"
            }]
}
```

Thanks to everyone for helping me learn this!

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through the `results` value of the JSON, but as you can see from your sample output, there is no such value. You need to iterate through `crs.features`.

```
$.each (json.crs.features, function (i, val) {
    name.push(val.properties.name);
    zip.push(val.properties.zip);
}
```

Comment: Ah! I am starting get how this works... its now telling me `Uncaught ReferenceError: crs is not defined`. Do i need to declare this somewhere?

Comment: Hah. This is really helping me make sense of the AJAX syntax! But unfortunately it is back to the original error. There are no error reports if I remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
dataType:"json",
```

to your `$.ajax` call. Does this fix it?

Comment: I think it is a problem with the iteration. I've been poking at it for a while. `json.features` returns the proper objects, but I still can't get down to the variables.

Comment: What do you get if you run: `$.each(json.results, function(i, val) {console.log(val)});`?

Comment: I think I finally figured it out.. something I thought I tried a long time ago, but this time it worked. I will post the solution.